# Hangfire and Dependency Injection Scoped

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, hangfire

I want to create a mechanism that executes a connection and disconnection from a service before and after each of my Hangfire jobs. I have build a service for that and registered it as scoped.

Before each job, I injected a filter. This filter should run my connect and disconnect. The problem is now that Hangfire creates my service in the filter once and once in my Job. But it should create it only once and use the same in the filter and job.

For my Hangfire I created an `Activator`:

```
public class ServiceJobActivator : JobActivator
{
    readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ServiceJobActivator(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        if (serviceScopeFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
        }

        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public override JobActivatorScope BeginScope(JobActivatorContext context)
    {
        return new ServiceJobActivatorScope(_serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope());
    }
}

public class ServiceJobActivatorScope : JobActivatorScope
{
    readonly IServiceScope _serviceScope;

    public ServiceJobActivatorScope(IServiceScope serviceScope)
    {
        if (serviceScope == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScope));
        }

        _serviceScope = serviceScope;
    }

    public override object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(_serviceScope.ServiceProvider, type);
        //return _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService(type);
    }
}
```

My job looks like this:

```
public class FileCleanerJob
{
    private IUnitofWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public FileCleanerJob(IUnitofWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Run(PerformContext context)
    {
        var hash = UnitofWork.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddHangfire((provider, config) => {
                config.UseActivator(new ServiceJobActivator(provider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()));
                config.UseFilter(new HangfireSessionFilter(provider.GetService<IUnitofWork>()));
            });
```

`HangfireSessionFilter.cs`:

```
public class HangfireSessionFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
{
    private readonly IUnitofWork UnitofWork;

    public HangfireSessionFilter(IUnitofWork unitofWork)
    {
        UnitofWork = unitofWork;
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        UnitofWork.Commit();
    }

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext context)
    {
        var hash = UnitofWork.GetHashCode();
        UnitofWork.BeginTransaction();
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the `Startup.cs` because `provider.GetService<IUnitofWork>()` is the root provider and I don't know hot to register it any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I could think of is to get rid of filter and upgrade the scope activator to invoke all logic that you need before pass it to Hangfire.

Important note to your code: it does not dispose your injected scope. See `DisposeScope` few code blocks below.

This is my starting setup for a test:

`/enqueue` method enqueues some work for UnitOfWork to make sure we have same instance everywhere

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.MemoryStorage;
using WebApplication1;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHangfire((provider, config) => {
    config
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseMemoryStorage();
        
    config.UseActivator(new ServiceJobActivator(provider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()));
});

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

builder.Services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapGet("/enqueue", () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enqueue endpoint is called");

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue<UnitOfWork>(uow => uow.Work());

    Console.WriteLine("Enqueue endpoint finished");

    return "OK";
});

app.Run();
```

Then the rest of the classes:

`UnitOfWork` - creates Id to track that duplicate scoped services are not created.

`ServiceJobActivator` - instantly creates `UnitOfWork` after scope is created and calls `Init` method

`ServiceJobActivatorScope` - scope is disposed in the end of job so it hooks into this event by overriding `DisposeScope`

```
using Hangfire;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        public readonly Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"UnitOfWork: contstructor - {Id}");

        }

        public void Init()
        {
            CheckIfDisposed();

            Console.WriteLine($"UnitOfWork: Init - {Id}");
        }

        public void Work()
        {
            CheckIfDisposed();

            Console.WriteLine($"UnitOfWork: Work - {Id}");
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            CheckIfDisposed();

            Console.WriteLine($"UnitOfWork: SaveChanges - {Id}");
        }

        private void CheckIfDisposed()
        {
            if (IsDisposed)
                throw new Exception("Error: UnitOfWork was already disposed");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"UnitOfWork: dispose - {Id}");
            IsDisposed = true;
        }

    }
    class ServiceJobActivator : JobActivator
    {
        readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public ServiceJobActivator(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }

        public override JobActivatorScope BeginScope(JobActivatorContext context)
        {
            var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();

            InitServices(scope);

            return new ServiceJobActivatorScope(scope);
        }

        private void InitServices(IServiceScope scope)
        {
            InitUnitOfWork(scope);
            // add other initializations here
        }

        private void InitUnitOfWork(IServiceScope scope)
        {
            var uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UnitOfWork>();

            uow.Init();
        }
    }

    class ServiceJobActivatorScope : JobActivatorScope
    {
        readonly IServiceScope _serviceScope;

        public ServiceJobActivatorScope(IServiceScope serviceScope)
        {
            _serviceScope = serviceScope;
        }

        public override object Resolve(Type type)
        {
            return _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);
        }

        public override void DisposeScope()
        {
            FinalizeServicesBeforeDispose();

            _serviceScope.Dispose();

            base.DisposeScope();
        }

        private void FinalizeServicesBeforeDispose()
        {
            SaveChangesInUnitOfWork();
            // add other method invokations that you would like to complete before dispose here
        }

        private void SaveChangesInUnitOfWork()
        {
            var uow = (UnitOfWork)Resolve(typeof(UnitOfWork));

            uow.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

}
```

Console output

[image: Console]